# I get a 403 Forbidden error on MacOS Monterrey, Apache 2.4

Tags: macos, permission, apache

On MacOS Monterrey, Apache 2.4, I get a 403 Forbidden page.

I changed the User / Group in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf, added "Include /etc/apache2/vhosts/adminer.conf" where adminer.conf content is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName adminer.local
        DocumentRoot "/Users/FRX32418/Documents/adminer"
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/adminer-error_log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/adminer-access_log common
        <directory "/Users/FRX32418/Documents/adminer">
                Require all granted
        </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In the logs, I get:

```
AH00132: file permissions deny server access: /Users/FRX32418/Documents/adminer/index.php
```

Need some help please.

Comment: And the permissions on that directory are...?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. The `Documents` folder is protected. You most probably need to grant the `httpd` binary access to `Documents` in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Files and Folders. Another possibility is to move `DocumentRoot` elsewhere, for example to `/Users/FRX32418/Sites/DocumentRoot`.

Comment: Make sure you have username:group match the actual folder's username/group.

```user _www``` ```group _www``` should be replaced with your actual username and group.